# Smarty personalized class using relative paths

Tags: php, smarty

I am currently working on making my smarty templates have a class.

If I take and do:

```
$smarty = new Smarty;
$smarty->setTemplateDir('../smarty/templates');
```

it sets my template directory to "/smarty/templates"...
so I'm trying to do the same in my class:

```
class Template extends Smarty
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->template_dir = "../smarty/templates/";
        $this->compile_dir = "../smarty/templates_c/";
    }
}
```

So I can simply say:

```
$smarty = new Template;
```

That way, I don't have to declare my directories for templates on each and every page I use.

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message
'Unable to load template file 'home.tpl'' in
/home/content/p/i/e/piec5762/html/alex/school/assets/php/smarty/sysplugins
/smarty_internal_templatebase.php:127
Stack trace:
#0
/home/content/p/i/e/piec5762/html/alex/school/assets/php/smarty/sysplugins
/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(374):
Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->fetch('home.tpl', NULL, NULL, NULL,
true)
#1
/home/content/p/i/e/piec5762/html/alex/school/index.php(40):
Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->display('home.tpl')
#2
{main} thrown in
/home/content/p/i/e/piec5762/html/alex/school/assets/php/smarty/sysplugins
/smarty_internal_templatebase.php on line 127
```

I have files:

```
index.php - where I'm making the object "$smarty"
assets/php/templates.php - where class Template
assets/smarty/templates - where I need to set the directory to
assets/php/smarty - where all my smarty files are
```

It's the same as this: [Extending PHP Smarty Singleton Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480563/extending-php-smarty-singleton-class) but more simplistic and sing RELATIVE PATHS

What am I supposed to do to set the template_dir in my own class?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I think he's trying to set the template_dir using his own class, but I believe he could do this by using a full path.

Comment: Can you post the error details?

Comment: @JScoobyCed, error has been posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED** following your error. It seems you are related to `index.php` so should be:

```
class Template extends Smarty {
  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setTemplateDir("./smarty/templates/");
    $this->setCompileDir("./smarty/templates_c/");
    }
  }
```

And if you want to be path safe:

```
class Template extends Smarty {
  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setTemplateDir(__DIR__."/../smarty/templates/");
    $this->setCompileDir(__DIR__."/../smarty/templates_c/");
    }
  }
```

Where `__DIR__` is the current file (i.e. your `templates.php` Template class) directory